# Is there a way to do batch translation using Azure's Cognitive Speach Services?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I am looking to use Azure's Speech to Text translation service while also getting speech diarization and it seems like diarization is only supported with the batch transcription API calls. Here are some relevant links:

Diarization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/conversation-transcription

Batch Transcription: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription

The speech translation and speech transcription APIs seem to be fairly identical: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-to-text

Is there something that I'm missing? I know Conversation Translation is in Preview so it might just not be available yet.

Moving forward, I believe the best solution right now is to do Speech Transcription and then Document Translation. Could please I get a confirmation or some pointers in a different direction.

Document Translation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/overview

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, the best solution at the moment is to do Speech Transcription using batch (with diarization, if you need it) in one step, and then do Translation as a separate step.